# how to keep track of previous parent of List objects in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

suppose I have these objects

```
class Person {
  @objc dynamic var personID = ""

  var pets = List<Pet>()

  override class func primaryKey() -> String?
     return "personID"
  }
}

class Pet {
  @objc dynamic var petID = ""

  private let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "pets")
  var owner: Person? { return owners.first }

  override class func primaryKey() -> String?
     return "petID"
  }
}
```

and I instantiate some objects

```
let john = Person()
john.personID = "abc"

let dog = Pet()
dog.petID = "dog"

let cat = Pet()
cat.petID = "cat"

let bird = Pet()
cat.petID = "bird"
```

Then do 2 assignments with different Pets for the same person

**Assignment 1**

```
john.pets = [dog, cat]
```

which means

```
dog.owner = john
cat.owner = john
bird.owner = nil
```

**Assignment 2**

```
john.pets = [cat, bird]
```

which means

```
dog.owner = nil
cat.owner = john
bird.owner = john
```

dog now becomes orphaned. is there a way to track that dog **was** owned by john?

Comment: This is a super question! For clarity doing this `john.pets = [dog, cat]` will not create the inverse relationship. It would need to be `john.pets.append(dog)` or `john.pets.append(objectsIn: [dog, cat])` to create that link. Since these objects are Objc under the hood, one approach would be KVO. That way if a pet is added, an event would fire enabling the pet to be stored, but within the pet, update a priorOwner property with that owner. If the pet is removed, the priorOwner property remains in place.

Comment: However, you can't KVO on LinkingObjects and while you can KVO on a List, you can't do it if its only in memory - it's only available once the List objects become managed. No solution for that yet but maybe someone else has a idea to expand on that approach.

Comment: The other issue is LinkingObjects - note that's plural. I personally dislike that as it doesn't create a one to many relationship, it creates a many to many so you have to code around it to guarantee singularity. So technically a pet could have multiple owners; in this case your object is returning the first owner in the owners property.